# full stack dapp clone example elastic supply algorithmic stablecoin

Tags: vyper, frontend, stablecoins, stack, clone

I'm new to vyper (but have some python experience), I would like to clone a very simple dapp to have a look at the full stack of an ethereum dapp from back end (write compile and deploy a simple contract) to an internet site as a front end facing the internet. where to find an example to have a look at all the details, to better understand all the components involved in the pipeline, and how they interact?
(if this is not the right place to ask, where should i ask?)

(I have a preference for elastic supply algorithmic stable coins as example)

Answer (score 0):

- There is an awesome vyper https://github.com/spadebuilders/awesome-vyper
- Uniswap v1 contracts were written in vyper https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v1. They switched to solidity for v2.
- There is vyperhub https://github.com/vyperhub-io/vyper-smart-contracts